# Tabs in the Contact Layout Editor (CLE) disappear when a Contact Type filter is added in FormBuilder

Tags: formbuilder, contact-layout-editor

I'm encountering some strange and frustrating behavior in the **Contact Layout Editor (CLE)** web UI.

My goal is to display custom tabs when viewing contacts of type Individual. The tabs show up on the left side in the Shoreditch theme.

I create the custom saved search and table search display via SearchKit.

I create the form to display the table search display via FormBuilder, ticking the box "Add to Contact Summary Page" and selecting "As Tab" under Form Settings > Placement. I do not specify any contact type in the "For" field. I save the form.

At this point, if I go into Contact Layout Editor, I can see my new tab at the top in the "System Default" layout. Yay.

However as soon as I go into FormBuilder and set a contact type "Individual" for the "Add to Contact Summary Page" > "As Tab" > "For" field, then *the new tab disappears from CLE "System Default" layout* (and any other custom layouts I have created in CLE).

This is unexpected. Why does the tab disappear in the CLE layouts?

Even if I create a custom layout in CLE for the specified contact type (Individual), that tab still doesn't show up. It's hidden in CLE for some odd reason.

If I go back into FormBuilder and clear the contact type "For" field, *then the tab reappears on the CLE "System Default" layout*. Great, at least I can get the tab back.

However this makes the CLE web UI practically useless if I can't trust that it's keeping the tabs, especially when I want to override the default tab ordering and visibility.

I have spent hours trying to figure this out and researching online without finding a solution.

It sure seems like a bug in CLE.

Am I missing something?

Appreciate any ideas. Thanks!

```
Here's my Dev Environment: 
 - Civicrm 5.62.0
 - Shoreditch civicrm theme 
 - Contact Layout Editor: Version 2.2.0
 - Drupal 10.0.9
```

Comment: HI. Welcome. can you replicate the issue on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ or does it not allow you the same combination of extensions etc. assuming it is not d10 specific. and have you tried switching the civi theme?

Comment: Thanks @petednz-fuzion. Yes, it's happening there as well. I just added a saved search, display table and a form in FormBuilder called "Test - Contributions". When you go into CLE System Default layout on that demo site, you'll see the tab appears and disappears depending on if a contact type filter is set or not in FormBuilder.

Comment: I haven't used CLE much. Have you tried changing themes for civi?

Comment: Yeah same issue if I switch from Shoreditch back to the default Greenwich backend theme.

Comment: So far I think I've narrowed it down to the Afform code that controls those tabs:

**[civicrm-core/ext/afform/core/afform.php > function afform_civicrm_tabset](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/8fc44dee73b6c88d05b5436c259e721aa89293ab/ext/afform/core/afform.php#L177)**

If I comment out the first if statement in the foreach loop, I get better results, but not perfect. 

I'm not setup to debug or do proper development on the code, so I hope someone can pick this up and look into it as a potential bug.

Comment: would be helpful if you could create an issue in gitlab https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues